# which image format is better to use in setup wizard in .NET?

Tags: c#, image, installation

i am using `.jpg` image format for setup wizard header but this image is `looking bad` with black doted. so which file of image is best to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project, then I think the image has to be 500x70 pixels in size.  Sizes other than this are scaled.  I don't think the format of the image matters.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is a graphic with straight edges and/or text then go for PNG.

If the image is a photograph then JPG would be acceptable.

JPG compression is great for photos that have lots of "blurry" edges but it produces artefacts when confronted with straight edges or text as it's compression algorithm is lossy. All in all you'd be best to use PNG.

I'd also make sure that it's the correct size for the area where it's displayed so there is no scaling - either up or down - needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a PNG. It's got lossless compression so should like nice without taking up much space. Generally it's the recommended unless size becomes a real issue.